Troubleshooting Nginx Proxy_Pass Issue: Traffic Not Redirected to Gunicorn Despite Correct Configurations. Site shows default Nginx welcome page
I have implemented Nginx as a reverse proxy to Gunicorn for serving a Django website. Despite verifying the configurations, the site continues to display the default Nginx welcome page upon visitation.
Below are configuration files for reference:
Gunicorn socket:
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target

Gunicorn daemon:
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/portfolio/myPortfolio
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/portfolio/env/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          portfolio.wsgi:application


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Nginx configuration file:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    location /staticfiles/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/portfolio/myPortfolio;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        log_not_found on;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/staticfiles.log debug;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /staticfiles$uri =404;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/portfolio/myPortfolio;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /mediafiles$uri =404;
    }



    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;


    location /staticfiles/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/portfolio/myPortfolio;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        log_not_found on;

error_log /var/log/nginx/staticfiles.log debug;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /staticfiles$uri =404;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/portfolio/myPortfolio;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /mediafiles$uri =404;
    }


location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

}



server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

Having carefully reviewed all relevant file paths and permissions multiple times, I can confirm their accuracy. However, despite investing a full working day in troubleshooting, the issue persists. While I have already explored most of the obvious solutions, I remain open to identifying any overlooked basic mistakes within the configurations.
